# The JVM constant pool index value must be greater than 0 to be valid, which is why?

Tags: java

The JVM constant pool index value must be greater than 0 to be valid, which is why? What are the advantages or uniqueness of such a design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `constant_pool` index value zero is reserved for other purposes.  For example, in the `ClassInfo` structure:

> `super_class`:  For  a  class,  the  value  of  the  `super_class` item  either  must  be  zero  or must  be  a  valid  index  into  the  `constant_pool` table.

I guess they decided it was better to use zero to represent "no value" than (say) 65535.  The original decision would have been made a long time ago.  Before Java was even called Java.

---

> What are the advantages or uniqueness of such a design?

Well you need to choose *some* some index value for the "no value" case, and there are only two logical choices for it ...

Comment: Thanks，I still have a question for you. I am using jdk8 virtual machine javap to look at the constant pool and found that the int type literal is not in the constant pool. Why is this, what has changed?

Comment: Presumably, the compiler doesn't include a constant pool entry because it is not required.  If this has changed, you should be able to find what it was by looking at the source code version history.